# Custom labels and custom labels deployments

Tags: deployment, customlabel

How to use custom labels in apex any syntax??

I have created more than 100 custom labels on my developer sandbox and added a translation text. when I create a change-set, add the custom labels to the change-set and deploy on production, only english text is deployed but translation text are not deployed.

Please let me know is there a better method to do this?

Answer (score 3):

When using change sets, translations are specified through `Language Translation`. Any translations you have set for Custom Labels, Custom Objects, Custom Fields, etc. in the Change Set will automatically be sent along for the languages you select:

[image]

When using a package based Metadata api deployment, the translations for Custom Labels are under [translations](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_translations.htm), as opposed to [custom object translations](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_customobjecttranslation.htm).

Answer (score 0):

- How to use custom labels in apex any syntax??

  Try `Label.**YourLabelName**`. Refer [using custom labels](http://www.sfdcpoint.com/salesforce/custom-label-in-apex-code-salesforce/).
- Deploy translations

  You can do it by change set itself. Add `Language Transition` for doing that. When you deploy please make sure that both the language translation and the component being translated must be included in the change set. Refer [deploy translations](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000170698&type=1)